# SPFX: How to create an <img> tag containing the photo BLOB returned by MSGraph photo/$value

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm creating somekind of custom Who-is-Who web part.

After retrieving the Users information with MSGraphClient /users API I'm trying to retrieve and display the Photo for each employee. I'm having a hard time finding the way to create a  tag with the information returned by /users/xxxx@xxxxxx.com/photo/$value.

I have tried different approaches but none succesfull. Let me share one to help you understand what I'm trying to achieve:

```
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    client.api('/users/xxxxx@xxxxx.com/photo/$value').get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
      const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(rawResponse.body);
      document.getElementById("myPhoto").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
    });
  });
```

Obviously my HTML has a - img id="myPhoto"- tag.
If possible I would like to avoid using React and the Persona view.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying that the response should be of type blob you should be able to do this:

```
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    client.api('/users/xxxxx@xxxxx.com/photo/$value')
      .responseType('blob').get().then((response: Blob) => {
        const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        document.getElementById("myPhoto").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
    });
```

Comment: YES!!! That was it!!! Thank you very much!!!